# Web clipping / note taking software on Linux

Tags: linux, evernote

I use this great web-clipping and note taking app called [Evernote](http://www.evernote.com/) on my Windows machine.

However, there's no Linux version of Evernote (doesn't work properly in Wine).

I would like to get some suggestions for something with similar capabilities that runs on Linux/Ubuntu.

- Specifically I need to be able to select parts of a web page in Firefox, and press some key combination, to save that clip to disk, in some sort of searchable database
- The clip needs to have pictures and basic text formatting, anything extra is unnecessary
- I also need to be able to create empty note or edit existing one.
- Storing the notes on a local machine only is fine - I don't need the sync features of Evernote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not familiar with Evernote, and I am not really sure what you mean by "clip". However, maybe you are looking for something like the Firefox extension called [Scrapbook](https://addons.mozilla.org/sv-SE/firefox/addon/427)?

With this extension, you can take a snapshot of a web page as you see it, adding notes and removing unwanted elements etc etc. If the web page is lost, or the information you're looking for is gone, then you still have your snapshot.

Comment: +check @Johan : Scrap does indeed "clip". What I meant by that is that you can select a portion of the webpage, and only that portion is saved to disk. Also, it actually saves to disk, so this is what I was after.

Answer (score 0):

use either the bookmarklet of '[evernote](http://www.evernote.com/about/download/web_clipper.php)' or the '[firefox addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/addon/8381)'.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Evernote Firefox add on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/8381/). There's more info on Evernote's page about the [web clipper](https://www.evernote.com/about/download/web_clipper.php).

Another option is the bookmarklet -- scroll to the bottom of the web clipper page for this.